# how await a hook after execute a query in apollo Gql and REACT?

Tags: reactjs, graph, next.js, react-apollo, apollo-client

i have the follow problem, i want to execute a query that need and ID user, but i have consult the ID user from a hook, the code:

```
export default function useGetDatosPersonales() {
  
    const [viewer, refetchViewer] =  useViewer();
    const {data} = useQuery(qUsuario,{
        variables: {
            user: viewer && viewer.id
        }
    });
    const functionCall = (render) => { 
       if(data !== null && data !== undefined){
           console.log(data.user.email);
        }
    }

    return [functionCall,data];
    
}
```

the query **qUsuario** is:

```
query qUsuario($user:ID!){
  user(id:$user){
    email,
    firstName,
    lastName,
  }
}
```

but in the first time i got the follow error:

> [GraphQL error]: **Variable "$user" of required type "ID!" was not
> provided.**

and then in few milliseconds later, the query works!

How i can say to the apollo that wait for the id before execute the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually), because useQuery don't wait never.

Or you may use async-await syntax for use client instance directly and have full control under asynchronous.